# How to iterate std::set?

Tags: c++, set, iteration

I have this code:

```
std::set<unsigned long>::iterator it;
for (it = SERVER_IPS.begin(); it != SERVER_IPS.end(); ++it) {
    u_long f = it; // error here
}
```

There is no `->first` value.
How I can obtain the value?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

You must dereference the iterator in order to retrieve the member of your set.

```
std::set<unsigned long>::iterator it;
for (it = SERVER_IPS.begin(); it != SERVER_IPS.end(); ++it) {
    u_long f = *it; // Note the "*" here
}
```

If you have C++11 features, you can use a [range-based for loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Range-based_for_loop):

```
for(auto f : SERVER_IPS) {
  // use f here
}
```

Comment: @Mr.C64 Not that it matters much with integral types as in this case.

Comment: It might be worth noting that you need to use the first one if you intend to modify the container. For the googlers that is.

Comment: I thing C++11 solution should be with reference (auto& f). It is better for most cases. For this specific case as well.

Comment: Hi Rob, what if I want to reference elements in SERVER_IPS other than  declare a new u_long variable? Can I use  u_long & f = *it; ? And if not, what should I do?

Comment: @BioCoder - You can use a reference variable, but it must be a **const** reference variable, like so: `const u_long& f = *it;`.

Comment: @Robᵩ You mean I can use a reference variable but I can't modify the content of it?

Comment: @BioCoder - that is correct. You cannot modify an element of an `std::set`.

Answer (score 22):

Another example for the C++11 standard:

```
set<int> data;
data.insert(4);
data.insert(5);

for (const int &number : data)
  cout << number;
```

Answer (score 19):

Just use the `*` before `it`:

```
set<unsigned long>::iterator it;
for (it = myset.begin(); it != myset.end(); ++it) {
    cout << *it;
}
```

This dereferences it and allows you to access the element the iterator is currently on.

Comment: Just a minor note: it is generally preferred to use ++it instead of it++ in for loops to avoid one extra copy of the iterator.

Answer (score 7):

**How do you iterate std::set?**

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) 
{
    std::set<int> mset;
    mset.insert(1); 
    mset.insert(2);
    mset.insert(3);

    for ( auto it = mset.begin(); it != mset.end(); it++ )
        std::cout << *it;
}
```

Comment: Or even `for(auto i : mset) std::cout << i;`

Answer (score 2):

One more thing that might be useful for beginners is since `std::set` is not allocated with contiguous memory chunks if someone want to iterate till `kth` element normal way will not work.

Example:

```
std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int k = 3;
for (auto itr = vec.begin(); itr < vec.begin() + k; itr++)
    cout << *itr << " ";
```

```
std::unordered_set<int> s{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int k = 3;
int index = 0;
auto itr = s.begin();
while (true)
{
    if (index == k)
        break;
    cout << *itr++ << " ";
    index++;
}
```