# How to get just first element of set in c++

Tags: c++, set

I am new to c++, I have declared set of sets:

```
std::set< std::set<int> > return_moves;
```

and also pushed some values in it. I want to access the first element of this set so that I can count a number of elements in that inner set. I am trying to get it by

```
return_moves.begin().size()
```

I am getting this error:

```
set_diff.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
set_diff.cpp:62:47: error: ‘std::set<std::set<int> >::iterator {aka struct std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::set<int> >}’ has no member named ‘size’
```

Please help me to rectify my syntax.

Comment: s/`return_moves.begin().size()`/`return_moves.begin()->size()`

Comment: A set has no concept of the first element.

Comment: @EdHeal then to access any element should i loop over it?

Comment: @user0042 your comment in is unclear to me.

Comment: Use `return_moves.begin()->size(()`

Comment: @SachinSingh The error message is pretty clear, no? You have a `std::set<std::set<int> >::iterator` and not a `std::set<int>`.

Comment: An iterator is in some some sense like a pointer, you need `->` not `.` to access the element size (rather than the iterator size, which doesn't exist.)

Answer (score 18):

Elaborating on Ed's comment, a set in `C++` is by default weakly ordered, so there is some guarantee to the iteration ordering, but as a mathematical concept there is no "order" in a set, and hence implementations do not usually allow obtaining a "first" element.

If you want just to obtain any element, without iterating you can use

```
auto someElementIterator = myset.begin()
```

which will return an iterator to some element. To "pop" it you can follow it with

```
myset.erase(someElementIterator)
```

and you can get the element using `*someElementIterator`.

Regarding your error:

An iterator is in some some sense like a pointer, you need -> not . To access the element size (rather than the iterator size, which doesn't exist). so:

```
someElementIterator->size()
```

and **not** `someElementIterator.size()`.

Comment: will erase method remove that element from `myset`?

Comment: @SachinSingh Yup.

Comment: it returns me `140728051101848` which is not the number of elements in ant of the inner set.

Comment: I updated the question and notified you in comments.

Comment: It is not the new question it is the question. see the edits I have done are to make it clear.

Comment: @kabanus regarding 'by definition an unordered collection of elements' ,  `std::set` follows [specific order](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/).

Comment: @miradham thanks, it was a while, I forgot the default `set` was actually ordered. Fixed.

Comment: It would be clearer if this said `int someElement = *return_moves.begin()` and then explained the iteration afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

I'm late sorry, i just passed and found the solution for next developpers.

To get the first element of the `std::set` you could just use :

```
std::set< std::set<int> > return_moves;
auto oneMove = *(return_moves.begin()); // will return the first set<int>

oneMove.size(); // will return the size of the first set<int>
```

Because `return_moves.begin()` return the iterator of the first element of the set, and by adding the `*` we will recive the value of the first element.

Answer (score 1):

A set has an iterator so you can loop over it like this [How to iterate std::set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863256/how-to-iterate-stdset)

`return_moves.begin()` returns an iterator to the "first" element (in laymen terms a better pointer to the "first" element). So

```
return_moves.begin()->size()
```

should be used instead.

I am using "first" element because that is the smallest element of the set according to the sorting criterion (it might be the first inserted but probably would be something else).